# Is there anyone now permanently living in 3D-printed houses or buildings?

Tags: 3d-design

Are the following statements still true, or are they now out of date?

> [3D printed architecture] The problem is this: No one has been able to successfully take the leap from printing a fancy art pavilion to printing a functional building, and it’s still not clear if the technology is going to save the world or be another decorative footnote of architectural history.

WinSun

> For whatever reason, the only printed buildings that look remotely habitable have been built by Chinese companies. But just because they look habitable doesn’t mean that they are. No one lives in these houses, and when you get close enough, they don’t really look like the kind of place you’d want to live, unless you have a thing for creepy-cave chic.
> (Both from https://architizer.com/blog/practice/details/3d-printed-buildings-future-or-gimmick/)

I'm not wanting to argue about the architectural concern for appearance.  As an engineer my concern is with structural integrity and reliability.  However, are people living in 3D houses?  That is the common concern.

Comment: I'd say I'd rather live in "creepy-cave chic" than not be able to afford a house at all...

Comment: There is no demonstration that these are any cheaper than using molds and pouring concrete.

Comment: @FourierFlux at that point the issue isn't material cost, but cost of equipment versus labor cost.  In the U.S. there is a labor shortage in construction.

Comment: Another issue with cost is there are multiple technologies and materials used for printing buildings.  Another issue is unless you hold labor wages now by essentially enslaving workers, the world will soon run out of cheap labor.  Automation is necessary for workers to produce more and get wages with a higher value.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently the article in the question is out of date:

Here's a family in France living in a 3D-printed house (95 sq.m. 1022 sq.ft.) since 2018:

"The world's first family to live in a 3D-printed home"
By Michael Cowan

BBC's Victoria Derbyshire programme

Published6 **July 2018**

https://www.bbc.com/news/technology-44709534

They essentially 3D-printed the form to poor the concrete in the house in France.  The form was insulation and stayed in place.  This many be an easier way to meet building codes.

And it looks like the market is picking up right now.  A year ago in Austin, a 400 sq.ft (37 sq.m.) home is very small for a family and doesn't compete with the traditional housing market.  However, the house in Austin shown in the picture looks huge.

[image]

REAL ESTATE:
"3D-printed housing developments suddenly take off – here’s what they look like"

PUBLISHED FRI, **MAR 12 2021** 3:36 PM ESTUPDATED MON, MAR 22 202111:53 AM EDT

https://www.cnbc.com/2021/03/12/3d-printed-housing-developments-suddenly-take-off-heres-what-they-look-like.html

Here's another link of someone building 3D printed houses for public sales:

https://www.iconbuild.com/updates/icon-delivers-series-of-3d-printed-homes-for-homeless

A Rising Trend:
7 Biggest Companies Building 3D Printed Houses:

https://all3dp.com/2/2019-best-companies-building-3d-printed-houses/

Comment: So the short answer is no; but there such a house up for sale.

Comment: Actually a family in France lives in 3D Printed house since 2018.